# FFmpeg stops encoding after x minutes when using Mjpeg

Tags: node.js, cmd, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg in a node application with this command:

```
ffmpeg -seekable 0 -i http://127.0.0.1:8100/Mjpeg/1?authToken=xxx -video_size 1280x720 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y D:\Video\pflyers\test.mp4
```

The encoding would stop after 28:53 every time. After some reading I figured I had to spawn the child instead of exec because of the large sterr output.

Before doing that I wanted to see if that was in fact the issue so I tried doing:

```
-nostats -hide_banner -loglevel panic
```

to avoid the large output to sterr. FFmpeg still stopped after 28:53. Further I tried to write the sterr to log.txt instead of using the above code. I did so adding this to the end:

```
2> log.txt
```

Still it would stop at 28:53.

Finally I tried running the command in cmd.exe resulting in the encoding stopping at 29:14.

What I realized comparing the outputs from ffmpeg run from node and run from cmd.exe was that the encoding stopped when the log.txt reached 388kB.

How can I fix this?

Here's the full output:

```
C:\Users\VossVind>ffmpeg -seekable 0 -i http://127.0.0.1:8100/Mjpeg/1?authToken=xxx -video_size 1280x720 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y D:\Video\pflyers\test.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mpjpeg, from 'http://127.0.0.1:8100/Mjpeg/1?authToken=xxx':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 96:96 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000019639b27fc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\Video\pflyers\test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
More than 1000 frames duplicated  114432kB time=00:03:17.80 bitrate=4739.3kbits/s dup=1000 drop=0 speed=0.95x
frame=52544 fps= 29 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1050136kB time=00:29:11.36 bitrate=4912.0kbits/s dup=8757 drop=0 speed=0.972x
video:1049508kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.059803%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] frame I:261   Avg QP:20.59  size: 51862
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] frame P:15400 Avg QP:23.72  size: 33007
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] frame B:36883 Avg QP:24.55  size: 14989
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] consecutive B-frames:  0.9% 15.8%  2.5% 80.8%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] mb I  I16..4: 17.1% 82.1%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] mb P  I16..4:  4.3% 48.4%  0.2%  P16..4: 12.3%  7.5%  4.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:22.5%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] mb B  I16..4:  2.7% 15.6%  0.0%  B16..8: 22.3%  7.0%  1.8%  direct: 3.8%  skip:46.8%  L0:52.3% L1:34.0% BI:13.8%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] 8x8 transform intra:88.6% inter:92.9%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 59.4% 33.6% 2.6% inter: 19.3% 10.9% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] i16 v,h,dc,p: 57% 30% 12%  1%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 18% 45%  2%  1%  1%  2%  2%  3%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 52% 24% 12%  2%  2%  2%  2%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] i8c dc,h,v,p: 63% 17% 20%  1%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] ref P L0: 43.8%  7.5% 29.1% 19.6%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] ref B L0: 71.8% 21.2%  7.0%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] ref B L1: 93.9%  6.1%
[libx264 @ 0000019639944040] kb/s:4908.78
```

Link to -v 48 verbose logging: https://pastebin.com/YwQx8bB2

Comment: Which node.js library are you using?

Comment: I discovered when using OGG/Theora instead of Mjpeg the error does not occur.

However, this does not solve my problem, because OGG/Theora takes too long to start recording. Mjpeg starts right away.

Any suggestions to either fix the mjpeg error or have OGG/Theora start straight away?

Comment: @sidhuko node version 9.2.0

Comment: Run with `-v 48 -report`. Share the report.

Comment: @Mulvya that is a 97mb file. So I skipped the repeated stuff in the middle.

https://pastebin.com/YwQx8bB2

Comment: Appears to be an input issue: `[out_0_0 @ 000001d32d931c40] EOF on sink link out_0_0:default.`

Comment: Okay, rather than looking at ffmpeg I should have a look at the source? Is there a way to ignore the false EOF? I tried searching for it, but found nothing useful.

Comment: @RuneAspvik EOF is not an error, which can be ignored. ffmpeg just has no more data to process, so the log says: `No more output streams to write to, finishing.` No sure what you source is but you have to correct it. Or as a workaround you can write multiple video files (start a new encoding if the old one stops) and merge them afterwards.

Comment: @UweMannl Thank you for replying. The source is a IP camera. I switched to rtsp stream, h264, and this works continuously, no EOF.

Comment: Glad to hear :)